# String array in c++ simple code

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops, do-while

here is my full program with c++ with do while loop, it works right the first time but when it loops it doesn't work correctly.

This program stores name into an array and prints it out.  array size is 50 so i want to store 50 names in the array.

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void start(int c);

string NameArray [50];
char response;

int main() {
  int count=1;  
  do {    
    count = count - 1;
    start(count);
    cout << "do you want to add another name? ";
    cin>> response;     
    count = count + 2;      
    cout<< endl;        
  } while (tolower(response)=='y');

  cout<< "program Ends" <<endl;        
  system ("pause");        
  return 0;     
}    

void start(int count) {         
  cout<< "Enter your First and Last name: ";        
  getline(cin, NameArray[count]);       
  cout<< NameArray[count] <<endl;       
  cout<< endl;          
}
```

Comment: Again and again, don't say `using namespace std;`!

Comment: Why do you start at `count=1;` then decrement it?  Why not skip that step and apply `count++;` on each iteration in your loop after the `cin>>response;` line?  Or even better, use a `static int count = -1; count++;` inside your `start` function and skip the `count` in `main` altogether...

Comment: That's a completely horrible loop index.  Start indexes at the first number (0), and increment it *after* adding an input. Indexes should only be incremented/decremented at one point within a loop, and only by +/-1.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a place where you dump your code, say "it doesn't work", then expect all the work in fixing it to just magically get done for you by other people, for free.

Answer (score 2):

The `cin>> response` will retrieve one character of input, and leave the newline character after it on the input stream. This will cause your `start()` function to return immediately after it prompts for your name, and `getline()` returns an empty line of input into `NameArray`.

You can instead use `getline()` to also retrieve your response as a string, and then check the first `char` of the line

```
    //...
    cout << "do you want to add another name? ";
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    response = line[0];
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use an explicit loop and break rather than a do while, as this allows you to avoid buffer overflows and neatens up the code. I've also added the fix from jxh's response. Something like this. (Untested)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void start(int c);

string NameArray [50];
std::string response;

int main() {
  for(int count=0; count<50; ++count) {
    start(count);
    cout << "do you want to add another name? ";
    std::getline(cin,response);
    if (tolower(response[0])=='y') break;
  }

  cout<< "program Ends" <<endl;        
  system ("pause");        
  return 0;     
}    

void start(int count) {         
  cout<< "Enter your First and Last name: ";        
  std::getline(cin, NameArray[count]);       
  cout<< NameArray[count] <<endl;       
  cout<< endl;          
}
```

But really the fixed length array is a problem that I'd avoid altogether, by using a vector instead. Then you can get rid of the count altogether. The code would look more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string ask_user_for_name();

std::vector<string> NameArray;

int main() {
  do {
    NameArray.push_back( ask_user_for_name() );
    std::string response;
    cout << "do you want to add another name? ";
    std::getline(cin,response);
    if (tolower(response[0])=='y') break;
  } while(true);

  cout<< "program Ends" <<endl;        
  system ("pause");        
  return 0;     
}    

std::string ask_user_for_name() {         
  cout<< "Enter your First and Last name: ";        
  std::string retval;
  getline(cin, retval);
  cout<<retval<<std::endl<<std::endl;
  return retval;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned stylistic issues, but the immediate problem is here:

```
  cout << "do you want to add another name? ";
  cin>> response;
  count = count + 2;      
  cout<< endl;        
} while (tolower(response)=='y');
```

In your `start()` function you correctly read in a complete line with `getline()`, but here your `cin >> response;` will leave a newline and perhaps other stuff in the input buffer. Instead try this:

```
std::string response;

//...

  cout << "do you want to add another name? ";
  getline(cin, response);  // Changed here
  count = count + 2;      
  cout<< endl;        
} while (tolower(response[0])=='y'); // And changed here
```

Comment: Thanks to all who have shared ideas, but ken Y-n and spartygw solution set me in the right direction which i needed.  - so now i will study this cin.ignore() some more - thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Guys are making this too complicated.  Your 2nd call to cin is reading a newline and returning immediate.  Here's the quickest fix:  add cin.ignore() right before your getline call:

```
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, NameArray[count]);
```

Comment: thanks alot spartygw this worked very well - it was just what i needed.

Comment: That won't work if the user types "yes" instead of "y", and other hacks like `cin.ignore(INT_MAX);` will not work properly if the input comes piped from a file.

Comment: Thanks for down voting my answer @Keyn Y-N

Comment: Well, you tried to make it too simple. And failed.